# MySQL Count duplicate cities for each country

Tags: mysql, sql, count

I'm trying to write a query against the cities table of the [World Database](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/index-other.html) that counts both the number of duplicate cities for each country, along with the duplicated values.  That part is working, but I'd also like to display the total duplicated cities for each country.

Here is my SQL (limited to one country for testing) so far:

```
Select c1.country_code, c1.city, citc.city_duplicates 
from cities c1 
join 
 (SELECT c2.id, c2.country_code, c2.city, COUNT(c2.city) AS `city_duplicates`  
    FROM cities c2
    WHERE c2.country_code = 'om'
    GROUP BY country_code, region_code, latitude, longitude, city 
    HAVING city_duplicates > 1
    ORDER BY country_code) citc
 on c1.id = citc.id;
```

And here are the results:

```
# country_code, city, city_duplicates
'om',           'zi', '2'
'om',           'zi', '2'
```

I'd like to see another column that says '4' for the country total.

Bonus points if you can sort by # of duplicates in desc order.

Here is some sample data:

```
# country_code, city, accent_city, region_code, population, latitude, longitude, id
'om', 'abailah', 'Abailah', '02', '0', '24.266666', '56.150002', '2050634'
'om', 'a`bal', 'A`bal', '05', '0', '24.433332', '56.049999', '2050635'
'om', '`abat', '`Abat', '04', '0', '22.550556', '59.328056', '2050636'
'om', '`abayah', '`Abayah', '06', '0', '23.175278', '58.814167', '2050637'
'om', '`abbasah', '`Abbasah', '02', '0', '23.916668', '57.216667', '2050638'
'om', '`ablah', '`Ablah', '05', '0', '23.168333', '56.909168', '2050639'
'om', 'abu `abali', 'Abu `Abali', '02', '0', '23.771111', '57.676945', '2050640'
'om', 'abu akaisha', 'Abu Akaisha', '04', '0', '21.400000', '59.283333', '2050641' 
om  zi  Z̧ahir  00  0   19.100000   56.966667   2053410
om  zi  Z̧abyah 02  0   24.350000   56.366669   2053408
ad  aixirivall  Aixirivall  06  0   42.466667   1.500000    3
ad  aixirvall   Aixirvall   06  0   42.466667   1.500000    4
ad  aixovall    Aixovall    06  0   42.466667   1.483333    5
ad  andorra Andorra 07  0   42.500000   1.516667    6
```

Here are the results with the country counts:

```
# country_code, city, city_duplicates, country_duplicates
'om',           'zi', '2',             '4'
'om',           'zi', '2',             '4'
```

Thanks!

Comment: show us sample data and expected output. and your links doesnt show World DB. Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

Comment: still you have to post something, I wont download the file just to help with your question

Comment: Dont use the comment, just edit your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You pretty much have to sum up the `city_duplicates` field in an outer query and join that to the results of the subquery, if you want to display the sum in another column:

```
SELECT c2.country_code, c2.city, COUNT(c2.city) AS `city_duplicates`, t2.country_duplicates
    FROM cities c2
    INNER JOIN (SELECT t.country_code, SUM(t.city_duplicates) as country_duplicates
                FROM (SELECT c3.country_code, c3.city, COUNT(c3.city) AS `city_duplicates`  
                      FROM cities c3
                      WHERE c3.country_code = 'om'
                      GROUP BY country_code, region_code, latitude, longitude, city 
                      HAVING city_duplicates > 1) t
                 GROUP BY t.country_code) t2 ON c2.country_code=t2.country_code
    WHERE c2.country_code = 'om'
    GROUP BY c2.country_code, region_code, latitude, longitude, city 
    HAVING city_duplicates > 1
    ORDER BY country_duplicates, c2.country_code
```

However, the code would be lot simpler if you wanted to have the summary in a separate record because you could use MySQL's [rollup](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-modifiers.html) group by` modifier.

Comment: Could you show me what the SQL would look like with rollup?  I'll try the query and see what the results look like.

Comment: Just add the `with rollup` to the end of the subquery in your original post (just remove the id field from the select list).

Answer (score 0):

Just sum your city duplicate count

```
 Select c1.country_code, c1.city, citc.city_duplicates ,sum(citc.city_duplicates) as country_duplicate 
from cities c1 
join 
 (SELECT c2.id, c2.country_code, c2.city, COUNT(c2.city) AS `city_duplicates`  
FROM cities c2
WHERE c2.country_code = 'om'
GROUP BY country_code, region_code, latitude, longitude, city 
HAVING city_duplicates > 1
ORDER BY country_code) citc
 on c1.id = citc.id group by c1.country_code order by c1.country_code desc;
```

Comment: The sum should be by country only, and the `on` clause is not at the end of the statement.

Comment: @jai dutt

That's exactly what I was thinking.  The only issue is that gets rid of all the duplicated city values and only shows the summary.  Is there a way to add that information while leaving each value as I showed in my results wishlist?

Comment: Bro just remove that group by c1.country_code and put some unique coloum may be your city id or something which is unique to get the required result

Comment: @jai dutt

Don't I need the group by to only retrieve cities that are true duplicates, i.e. that have the same geodata, region, etc?

Comment: @RobGravelle you cannot do this the way Jai Dutt suggested.

Comment: hI @SHADOW thanks for correct me and teach me new things like rollup